# Perl module LWP::Protocol::https installation fails on Ubuntu

Tags: perl, ubuntu, ssl, cpan, lwp-useragent

Wanting to use `LWP::UserAgent` on an HTTPS resource, I was asked to install missing module `LWP::Protocol::https`. Fine.

I'm on *Ubuntu 13.04*. I ran `'install LWP::Protocol::https'` under *cpan* prompt but installation fails (see log below).

Any idea ?

Thanks

```
cpan[10]> install LWP::Protocol::https
Running install for module 'LWP::Protocol::https'
Running make for G/GA/GAAS/LWP-Protocol-https-6.04.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/LWP-Protocol-https-6.04-A81I35
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----    GAAS/LWP-Protocol-https-6.04.tar.gz   ----
    IO::Socket::SSL [requires]
Running make test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module 'IO::Socket::SSL'
Running make for S/SU/SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----     SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981.tar.gz     ----
    Net::SSLeay [requires]
Running make test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module 'Net::SSLeay'
Running make for M/MI/MIKEM/Net-SSLeay-1.58.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/Net-SSLeay-1.58-KYAjpu
Could not make: Unknown error
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Running make for S/SU/SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx
Warning: Prerequisite 'Net::SSLeay => 1.46' for 'SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981.tar.gz' failed when processing 'MIKEM/Net-SSLeay-1.58.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
  Has already been made
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t t/external/*.t
t/01loadmodule.t .................. 1/3 
#   Failed test 'loaded'
#   at t/01loadmodule.t line 8.
Undefined subroutine &Net::SSLeay::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER called at t/01loadmodule.t line 10.
# Looks like you planned 3 tests but ran 1.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1 run.
# Looks like your test exited with 2 just after 1.
t/01loadmodule.t .................. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 3/3 subtests 
t/acceptSSL-timeout.t ............. Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 17.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 17.
Compilation failed in require at t/acceptSSL-timeout.t line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/acceptSSL-timeout.t line 3.
t/acceptSSL-timeout.t ............. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/auto_verify_hostname.t .......... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/auto_verify_hostname.t line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/auto_verify_hostname.t line 5.
t/auto_verify_hostname.t .......... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/cert_no_file.t .................. Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/cert_no_file.t line 16.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/cert_no_file.t line 16.
t/cert_no_file.t .................. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/compatibility.t ................. Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 17.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 17.
Compilation failed in require at t/compatibility.t line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/compatibility.t line 7.
t/compatibility.t ................. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/connectSSL-timeout.t ............ Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 17.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 17.
Compilation failed in require at t/connectSSL-timeout.t line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/connectSSL-timeout.t line 3.
t/connectSSL-timeout.t ............ Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/core.t .......................... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/core.t line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/core.t line 7.
t/core.t .......................... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/dhe.t ........................... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/dhe.t line 13.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/dhe.t line 13.
t/dhe.t ........................... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/ecdhe.t ......................... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/ecdhe.t line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/ecdhe.t line 7.
t/ecdhe.t ......................... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/external/usable_ca.t ............ Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 17.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 17.
Compilation failed in require at t/external/usable_ca.t line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/external/usable_ca.t line 4.
t/external/usable_ca.t ............ Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/io-socket-inet6.t ............... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/io-socket-inet6.t line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/io-socket-inet6.t line 14.
t/io-socket-inet6.t ............... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/io-socket-ip.t .................. Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/io-socket-ip.t line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/io-socket-ip.t line 10.
t/io-socket-ip.t .................. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/memleak_bad_handshake.t ......... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/memleak_bad_handshake.t line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/memleak_bad_handshake.t line 7.
t/memleak_bad_handshake.t ......... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/mitm.t .......................... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/mitm.t line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/mitm.t line 5.
t/mitm.t .......................... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/nonblock.t ...................... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/nonblock.t line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/nonblock.t line 8.
t/nonblock.t ...................... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/npn.t ........................... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/npn.t line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/npn.t line 7.
t/npn.t ........................... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/public_suffix_lib_encode_idn.t .. ok     
t/public_suffix_lib_libidn.t ...... ok     
t/public_suffix_lib_uri.t ......... ok     
t/public_suffix_ssl.t ............. Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 17.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 17.
Compilation failed in require at t/public_suffix_ssl.t line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/public_suffix_ssl.t line 3.
t/public_suffix_ssl.t ............. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/readline.t ...................... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/readline.t line 16.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/readline.t line 16.
t/readline.t ...................... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/sessions.t ...................... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/sessions.t line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/sessions.t line 7.
t/sessions.t ...................... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/signal-readline.t ............... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/signal-readline.t line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/signal-readline.t line 5.
t/signal-readline.t ............... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/sni.t ........................... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/sni.t line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/sni.t line 5.
t/sni.t ........................... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/start-stopssl.t ................. Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 17.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 17.
Compilation failed in require at t/start-stopssl.t line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/start-stopssl.t line 6.
t/start-stopssl.t ................. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/startssl-failed.t ............... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/startssl-failed.t line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/startssl-failed.t line 5.
t/startssl-failed.t ............... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/startssl.t ...................... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/startssl.t line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/startssl.t line 7.
t/startssl.t ...................... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/sysread_write.t ................. Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/sysread_write.t line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/sysread_write.t line 11.
t/sysread_write.t ................. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/verify_fingerprint.t ............ Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 17.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 17.
Compilation failed in require at t/verify_fingerprint.t line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/verify_fingerprint.t line 4.
t/verify_fingerprint.t ............ Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 
t/verify_hostname.t ............... Can't locate Net/SSLeay.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981-BlA8cx/blib/arch /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at t/verify_hostname.t line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/verify_hostname.t line 5.
t/verify_hostname.t ............... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/01loadmodule.t                (Wstat: 512 Tests: 1 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 3 tests but ran 1.
t/acceptSSL-timeout.t           (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/auto_verify_hostname.t        (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/cert_no_file.t                (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/compatibility.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/connectSSL-timeout.t          (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/core.t                        (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/dhe.t                         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/ecdhe.t                       (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/external/usable_ca.t          (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/io-socket-inet6.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/io-socket-ip.t                (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/memleak_bad_handshake.t       (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/mitm.t                        (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/nonblock.t                    (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/npn.t                         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/public_suffix_ssl.t           (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/readline.t                    (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/sessions.t                    (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/signal-readline.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/sni.t                         (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/start-stopssl.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/startssl-failed.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/startssl.t                    (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/sysread_write.t               (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/verify_fingerprint.t          (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
t/verify_hostname.t             (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=30, Tests=250,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.13 usr  0.06 sys +  0.38 cusr  0.08 csys =  0.65 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 27/30 test programs. 1/250 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 2
  SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981.tar.gz
one dependency not OK (Net::SSLeay); additionally test harness failed
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Running make for G/GA/GAAS/LWP-Protocol-https-6.04.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/LWP-Protocol-https-6.04-A81I35
Warning: Prerequisite 'IO::Socket::SSL => 1.54' for 'GAAS/LWP-Protocol-https-6.04.tar.gz' failed when processing 'SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981.tar.gz' with 'make_test => NO one dependency not OK (Net::SSLeay); additionally test harness failed'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
  Has already been made
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/apache.t .. 1/4 
#   Failed test at t/apache.t line 15.

#   Failed test at t/apache.t line 16.
#                   'LWP will support https URLs if the LWP::Protocol::https module
# is installed.
# '
#     doesn't match '(?^:Apache Software Foundation)'

#   Failed test at t/apache.t line 23.
# Looks like you failed 3 tests of 4.
t/apache.t .. Dubious, test returned 3 (wstat 768, 0x300)
Failed 3/4 subtests 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/apache.t (Wstat: 768 Tests: 4 Failed: 3)
  Failed tests:  1-3
  Non-zero exit status: 3
Files=1, Tests=4,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.00 sys +  0.08 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.10 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/1 test programs. 3/4 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 3
  GAAS/LWP-Protocol-https-6.04.tar.gz
one dependency not OK (IO::Socket::SSL); additionally test harness failed
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports GAAS/LWP-Protocol-https-6.04.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 GAAS/LWP-Protocol-https-6.04.tar.gz          : make_test NO one dependency not OK (IO::Socket::SSL); additionally test harness failed
 SULLR/IO-Socket-SSL-1.981.tar.gz             : make_test NO one dependency not OK (Net::SSLeay); additionally test harness failed
```

Comment: Net::SSLeay's installation failed, but we can't see the problem because of "Has already been unwrapped into directory". Do: 1) `cpan`, 2) `o conf build_dir_reuse 0`, 3) `o conf commit`, 4) `exit`, 5) Try installation again and update output. Or rather, do 6) `cpan Net::SSLeay`. We don't need the noise of IO::Socket::SSL or LWP::Protocol::https.

Comment: You probably just need to install `libssl` first. `sudo apt-get install libssl` should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answar, I try `sudo apt-get install liblwp-protocol-https-perl`, then is fine to run my script which used LWP module and error with "LWP will support https URLs if the LWP::Protocol::https module is installed.", Before installed, I use cpan install `LWP::Protocol::https` and it didn't work for solving script's error.

Answer (score 8):

Because you are running cpan as root I assume you just want to add this module to the perl shipping with ubuntu. In this case just install liblwp-protocol-https-perl.

Otherwise, if you want to build it yourself:
LWP::Protocol::https requires IO::Socket::SSL which requires Net::SSLeay which needs the OpenSSL header files and libraries. So if you want to build it yourself you need libssl-dev.

Comment: Thank u all ! I tried to install libssl (sudo apt-get install libssl)  but this fails saying libssl is missing or obsolete.

Comment: libssl should probably be installed already because lots of programs depend on it. What you need is libssl-dev. Please also note that 13.04 is end-of-life, so you will not get a libssl with patches against heartbleed attack.

Comment: `apt-get install liblwp-protocol-https-perl` worked for me, followed by `install LWP::Protocol::https` in cpan. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It's ok now.

I run 'sudo apt-get install libssl-dev' then 'sudo cpan install LWP::Protocol::https'

All went fine.

Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

install the libssl-dev package [SSLeay.xs](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MIKEM/Net-SSLeay-1.58/SSLeay.xs) includes a number of headers(  etc) and these are found in the [libssl-dev package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/amd64/libssl-dev/filelist) in Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail.